# index was out of range in vb .net while executing crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a vb.net code like this: i am working on vb.net windows form, am trying to execute crystal report that included 3 subreports..i given my code like this:

```
Dim locid As Integer = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", CmbLocations.Text)
        Dim ptime As Integer = TxtTime.Text
        'ViolatedRequested
        Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("IBS_Delivarysummaryviolatedrequested", con.connect)
        cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        cmd23.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ptime
        da.SelectCommand = cmd23
        da.Fill(ds)
        Dim rpt As New DelivarySummerystatuswiserpt
        ' If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

        rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
        ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        '  End If
        'requested
        Dim cmdreqstd As New SqlCommand("IBS_Delivarysummaryrequested", con.connect)
        cmdreqstd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdreqstd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        cmdreqstd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ptime
        da.SelectCommand = cmdreqstd
        da.Fill(ds1)
        rpt.Subreports(1).SetDataSource(ds1.Tables(0))
        ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt

        ''  Parked
        Dim cmdparked As New SqlCommand("IBS_Delivarysummaryparked", con.connect)
        cmdparked.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdparked.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        da.SelectCommand = cmdparked
        da.Fill(ds2)
        rpt.Subreports(2).SetDataSource(ds2.Tables(0))
        ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt

        'violated Detaild
        Dim cmdvolatedDetaild As New SqlCommand("IBS_DelivarysummaryviolateDetaild", con.connect)
        cmdvolatedDetaild.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdvolatedDetaild.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        cmdvolatedDetaild.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ptime
        da.SelectCommand = cmdvolatedDetaild
        da.Fill(ds3)
        If (ds3.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
            rpt.Subreports(3).SetDataSource(ds3.Tables(0))
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        End If
```

while executing i am getting error in  this line  ***rpt.Subreports(3).SetDataSource(ds3.Tables(0))***

getting error like this:
*Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index*
what is wrong with my code,,if any know please help me to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say that you have 3 subreports, then your subreport indexes are 0,1, and 2. So there is no index 3 and that's why you are getting the error. It should be

```
rpt.Subreports(0)
rpt.Subreports(1)
rpt.Subreports(2)
```